# What's wrong with System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression class?

Tags: .net, expression-trees

I'm trying to parse Expression and at some point I have to parse expressions with type `System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression`. This class name I take from debug watch. `expression.GetType().ToString()` equals `"System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression"`. But I cant see this class in `System.Linq.Expressions` namespace. Nowhere at all. The same thing with `MethodBinaryExpression` class.

In order to check type I really prefer to write

- `expression is LogicalBinaryExpression` or
- `expression.GetType() = typeof(LogicalBinaryExpression )` but definitely not
- `expression.GetType().ToString() == "System.Linq.Expressions.LogicalBinaryExpression"`

So now I just have error

> The type or namespace name 'LogicalBinaryExpression' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Linq.Expressions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

How this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`LogicalBinaryExpression` is `internal`, so:

1. It's more difficult to get is as a `Type`, you can't simply use `typeof(LogicalBinaryExpression)` or `x is LogicalBinaryExpression`.
2. You won't find any documentation about it.
3. You shouldn't use it at all. It's an implementation detail that can change any time.

You should either check for [`BinaryExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.aspx), or check the [`NodeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.nodetype.aspx) of the expression.

The same applies to `MethodBinaryExpression`.